# Possible basis for Lie algebra $su(4)$

Tags: representation-theory

Is it possible to construct a basis of $su(4)$ such that for any pair of elements of that basis we satisfy the following property, $$\{f_{\mu},f_{\nu}\}=2\delta_{\mu \nu}f_{\mu}^2,$$ where $\{A,B\}=AB+BA$? This is just an extension of the well-known basis of $su(2)$ given by the Pauli's matrices which satisfies the mentioned property.

Comment: You can't multiply elements of an algebra or compute the anticommutator. Do you mean, is there a representation of $su(4)$ in which there exists a basis where your equation is true?

Comment: No. Use [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221851/the-anticommutator-of-sun-generators) to prove it.